Windows Server AD DS LDAP switched servers
I have a Windows Server 2022, there's 2 DCs, 192.168.1.9 and 192.168.1.20.
The main one is supposed to be 192.168.1.9 and as far as I've been told the 192.168.1.20 is to isolate connections coming from the outside and should be used by our work computers.
While I was trying to set up DHCP and DNS in 192.168.1.9, at some point I guess I messed up (maybe forcing some replication or something) and now
ldapsearch -H ldap://192.168.1.9:389 -b "dc=MYORG,dc=COM" -W -D "CN=Daviid,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM" "sAMAccountName=daviid"
has stopped working, I can however do
ldapsearch -H ldap://192.168.1.20:389 -b "dc=MYORG,dc=COM" -W -D "CN=Daviid,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM" "sAMAccountName=daviid"
I can access both IPs through RDP and can access the Server Admin app.
Also for whatever reason, if I restart the server I see an error in AD DS where IsmServ wasn't able to start. Sometimes I can just start it right up and sometimes I have to do netsh iplisten delete ipaddress=<Server IP> to start it.

ldapsearch with -d 1
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://192.168.1.9:389)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://192.168.1.9:389/??base)
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.1.9:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.1.9:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
ber_flush2: 65 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x55e30ad5f970 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x55e30ad5f970 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55e30ad5f970 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x55e30ad5f970 Connections:
* host: 192.168.1.9  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=172.30.91.5:40910
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue May 28 11:53:05 2024


** ld 0x55e30ad5f970 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55e30ad5f970 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55e30ad5f970 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55e30ad5f970 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55e30ad5f970 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55e30ad5f970 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55e30ad5f970 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ldap_err2string
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
ldap_do_free_request: asked to free lr 0x55e30ad5ff30 msgid 1 refcnt 0
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_free_connection: actually freed

ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://192.168.1.20:389)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://192.168.1.20:389/??base)
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.1.20:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.1.20:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
ber_flush2: 65 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Connections:
* host: 192.168.1.20  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=172.30.91.5:40524
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue May 28 11:56:48 2024


** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55a2156b6970 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 16 contents:
ldap_find_request_by_msgid: msgid 1, lr 0x55a2156b6f30 lr->lr_refcnt = 1
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 1 message type bind
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_return_request: lrx 0x55a2156b6f30, lr 0x55a2156b6f30
ldap_return_request: lrx->lr_msgid 1, lrx->lr_refcnt is now 0, lr is still present
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_free_request_int: lr 0x55a2156b6f30 msgid 1 removed
ldap_do_free_request: asked to free lr 0x55a2156b6f30 msgid 1 refcnt 0
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=MYORG,dc=COM> with scope subtree
# filter: sAMAccountName=daviid
# requesting: ALL
#

ldap_search_ext
put_filter: "sAMAccountName=daviid"
put_filter: default
put_simple_filter: "sAMAccountName=daviid"
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush2: 75 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Connections:
* host: 192.168.1.20  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=172.30.91.5:40524
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue May 28 11:56:48 2024


** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55a2156b6970 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 2381 contents:
ldap_find_request_by_msgid: msgid 2, lr 0x55a2156b77a0 lr->lr_refcnt = 1
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 2 message type search-entry
ldap_return_request: lrx 0x55a2156b77a0, lr 0x55a2156b77a0
ldap_return_request: lrx->lr_msgid 2, lrx->lr_refcnt is now 0, lr is still present
ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
ldap_dn2ufn
ldap_dn_normalize
# D , Users, MYORG.COM
dn: CN=D ,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
cn: D 
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
sn: 
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
title: Informatico
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
telephoneNumber: 675749325
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
givenName: David
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
distinguishedName: CN=D ,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
instanceType: 0
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
whenCreated: 20230202095650.0Z
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
whenChanged: 20240527054431.0Z
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
displayName: Daviid
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
uSNCreated: 8436
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
memberOf: CN=Administradores de DHCP,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
memberOf: CN=Pidgin,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
memberOf: CN=docker-users,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
memberOf: CN=RDP,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
memberOf: CN=Administradores,CN=Builtin,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
uSNChanged: 9967482
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
department: Informatica
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
company: mycompany
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
name: D 
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
objectGUID:: fiGpZHOHNUqNEADE/OJRzA==
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
userAccountControl: 66048
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
badPwdCount: 0
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
codePage: 0
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
countryCode: 0
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
badPasswordTime: 133613619803759311
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
lastLogon: 133613622043600152
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
pwdLastSet: 133198054102241526
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
primaryGroupID: 513
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
objectSid:: AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAhY271gvS/IWYBzeIUwQAAA==
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
adminCount: 1
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
logonCount: 272
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
sAMAccountName: daviid
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
sAMAccountType: 805306368
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
managedObjects: CN=Pidgin,CN=Users,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
userPrincipalName: daviid@MYORG.COM
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
dSCorePropagationData: 20230227100643.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000000.0Z
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
lastLogonTimestamp: 133612622645125490
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
msDS-RevealedDSAs: CN=EVSERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
msDS-RevealedDSAs: CN=EVSERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
msDS-RevealedDSAs: CN=EVSERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
msDS-RevealedDSAs: CN=EVSERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
msDS-RevealedDSAs: CN=EVSERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
msDS-AuthenticatedAtDC: CN=EVSERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=MYORG,DC=C
 OM
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
mail: daviid@mycompany.com
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({mM}) ber:
mobile: 675749325
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Connections:
* host: 192.168.1.20  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=172.30.91.5:40524
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue May 28 11:56:48 2024


** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55a2156b6970 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 90 contents:
ldap_find_request_by_msgid: msgid 2, lr 0x55a2156b77a0 lr->lr_refcnt = 1
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 2 message type search-reference
ldap_return_request: lrx 0x55a2156b77a0, lr 0x55a2156b77a0
ldap_return_request: lrx->lr_msgid 2, lrx->lr_refcnt is now 0, lr is still present

# search reference
ber_scanf fmt ({v) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ref: ldap://DomainDnsZones.MYORG.COM/DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=MYORG,
 DC=COM
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Connections:
* host: 192.168.1.20  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=172.30.91.5:40524
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue May 28 11:56:48 2024


** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55a2156b6970 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 90 contents:
ldap_find_request_by_msgid: msgid 2, lr 0x55a2156b77a0 lr->lr_refcnt = 1
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 2 message type search-reference
ldap_return_request: lrx 0x55a2156b77a0, lr 0x55a2156b77a0
ldap_return_request: lrx->lr_msgid 2, lrx->lr_refcnt is now 0, lr is still present

# search reference
ber_scanf fmt ({v) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ref: ldap://ForestDnsZones.MYORG.COM/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=MYORG,
 DC=COM
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Connections:
* host: 192.168.1.20  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=172.30.91.5:40524
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue May 28 11:56:48 2024


** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55a2156b6970 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 74 contents:
ldap_find_request_by_msgid: msgid 2, lr 0x55a2156b77a0 lr->lr_refcnt = 1
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 2 message type search-reference
ldap_return_request: lrx 0x55a2156b77a0, lr 0x55a2156b77a0
ldap_return_request: lrx->lr_msgid 2, lrx->lr_refcnt is now 0, lr is still present

# search reference
ber_scanf fmt ({v) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ref: ldap://MYORG.COM/CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Connections:
* host: 192.168.1.20  port: 389  (default)
* from: IP=172.30.91.5:40524
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Tue May 28 11:56:48 2024


** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55a2156b6970 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55a2156b6970 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55a2156b6970 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 16 contents:
ldap_find_request_by_msgid: msgid 2, lr 0x55a2156b77a0 lr->lr_refcnt = 1
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 2 message type search-result
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x55a2156b6970 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 2
request done: ld 0x55a2156b6970 msgid 2
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_return_request: lrx 0x55a2156b77a0, lr 0x55a2156b77a0
ldap_return_request: lrx->lr_msgid 2, lrx->lr_refcnt is now 0, lr is still present
ldap_free_request (origid 2, msgid 2)
ldap_free_request_int: lr 0x55a2156b77a0 msgid 2 removed
ldap_do_free_request: asked to free lr 0x55a2156b77a0 msgid 2 refcnt 0

# search result
search: 2
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_err2string
result: 0 Success
ldap_msgfree

# numResponses: 5
# numEntries: 1
# numReferences: 3
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_send_unbind
ber_flush2: 7 bytes to sd 3
ldap_free_connection: actually freed

ldp.exe connection output
ld = ldap_open("192.168.1.9", 389);
Established connection to 192.168.1.9.
Retrieving base DSA information...
Server error: <empty>
Error<94>: ldap_parse_result failed: No result present in message
Server error: <empty>
Getting 0 entries:
-----------
Server error: <empty>

ld = ldap_open("192.168.1.20", 389);
Established connection to 192.168.1.20.
Retrieving base DSA information...
Getting 1 entries:
Dn: (RootDSE)
configurationNamingContext: CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; 
currentTime: 5/28/2024 12:41:55 PM Romance Daylight Time; 
defaultNamingContext: DC=MYORG,DC=COM; 
dnsHostName: DC2.MYORG.COM; 
domainControllerFunctionality: 7 = ( WIN2016 ); 
domainFunctionality: 5 = ( WIN2012 ); 
dsServiceName: CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; 
forestFunctionality: 5 = ( WIN2012 ); 
highestCommittedUSN: 9989816; 
isGlobalCatalogReady: TRUE; 
isSynchronized: TRUE; 
ldapServiceName: MYORG.COM:DC2$@MYORG.COM; 
namingContexts (5): DC=MYORG,DC=COM; CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; 
rootDomainNamingContext: DC=MYORG,DC=COM; 
schemaNamingContext: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; 
serverName: CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; 
subschemaSubentry: CN=Aggregate,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MYORG,DC=COM; 
supportedCapabilities (7): 1.2.840.113556.1.4.800 = ( ACTIVE_DIRECTORY ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1670 = ( ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_V51 ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1791 = ( ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_LDAP_INTEG ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1935 = ( ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_V61 ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2080 = ( ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_V61_R2 ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2237 = ( ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_W8 ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1920 = ( ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_PARTIAL_SECRETS ); 
supportedControl (38): 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319 = ( PAGED_RESULT ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.801 = ( SD_FLAGS ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.473 = ( SORT ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.528 = ( NOTIFICATION ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.417 = ( SHOW_DELETED ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.619 = ( LAZY_COMMIT ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.841 = ( DIRSYNC ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.529 = ( EXTENDED_DN ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.805 = ( TREE_DELETE ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.521 = ( CROSSDOM_MOVE_TARGET ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.970 = ( GET_STATS ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1338 = ( VERIFY_NAME ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.474 = ( RESP_SORT ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1339 = ( DOMAIN_SCOPE ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1340 = ( SEARCH_OPTIONS ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1413 = ( PERMISSIVE_MODIFY ); 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.9 = ( VLVREQUEST ); 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.10 = ( VLVRESPONSE ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1504 = ( ASQ ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1852 = ( QUOTA_CONTROL ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.802 = ( RANGE_OPTION ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1907 = ( SHUTDOWN_NOTIFY ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1948 = ( RANGE_RETRIEVAL_NOERR ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1974 = ( FORCE_UPDATE ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1341 = ( RODC_DCPROMO ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2026 = ( DN_INPUT ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2064 = ( SHOW_RECYCLED ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2065 = ( SHOW_DEACTIVATED_LINK ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2066 = ( POLICY_HINTS_DEPRECATED ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2090 = ( DIRSYNC_EX ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2205 = ( UPDATE_STATS ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2204 = ( TREE_DELETE_EX ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2206 = ( SEARCH_HINTS ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2211 = ( EXPECTED_ENTRY_COUNT ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239 = ( POLICY_HINTS ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2255 = ( SET_OWNER ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2256 = ( BYPASS_QUOTA ); 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2309 = ( LINK_TTL ); 
supportedLDAPPolicies (20): MaxPoolThreads; MaxPercentDirSyncRequests; MaxDatagramRecv; MaxReceiveBuffer; InitRecvTimeout; MaxConnections; MaxConnIdleTime; MaxPageSize; MaxBatchReturnMessages; MaxQueryDuration; MaxDirSyncDuration; MaxTempTableSize; MaxResultSetSize; MinResultSets; MaxResultSetsPerConn; MaxNotificationPerConn; MaxValRange; MaxValRangeTransitive; ThreadMemoryLimit; SystemMemoryLimitPercent; 
supportedLDAPVersion (2): 3; 2; 
supportedSASLMechanisms (4): GSSAPI; GSS-SPNEGO; EXTERNAL; DIGEST-MD5; 

-----------


1.20 is 2016 actually, syncal gives LDAP error 81 (Server Down) Win32 Err 58. on 192.168.1.9 and
Sincronizando todos los NC guardados en EVSERVER.
Sincronizando partición: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=ENERKAGLOBAL,DC=COM
MENSAJE DE DEVOLUCION DE LLAMADA: Error al establecer contacto con el servidor CN=NTDS Settings,CN=EVSERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=ENERKAGLOBAL,DC=COM (error de red):
1722 (0x6ba):
    El servidor RPC no está disponible.

SyncAll se finalizó con error grave de Win32: 8440 (0x20f8):
    El contexto del nombre especificado en la operación de replicación no es válido.


on 192.168.1.20
Both have their own IP as first DNS and 127.0.0.1 as second.
So 192.168.1.9 has 192.168.1.9 as primary DNS and 127.0.0.1 as secondary
and 192.168.1.20 has 192.168.1.20 as primary DNS and 127.0.0.1 as secondary
as for using ldap instead of ldaps I hadn't gotten around to configuring ldaps.
dcdiag output
192.168.1.9
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = DC1
   Ldap search capability attribute search failed on server DC1, return value = 52

192.168.1.20
Diagnóstico del servidor de directorio

Realizando instalación inicial:
   Intentando encontrar el servidor principal...
   Servidor principal = DC2
   * Se identificó el bosque de AD.
   Recopilación de información inicial finalizada.

Realizando pruebas requeridas iniciales

   Probando servidor: Default-First-Site-Name\DC2
      Iniciando prueba: Connectivity
         El host bb2ad125-79e5-4d8a-975a-c9e62e1827a7._msdcs.MYORGANIZATION.COM no se pudo resolver en una dirección IP. Compruebe el servidor DNS, el DHCP, el nombre de servidor, etc.
         Error al comprobar la conectividad de LDAP y RPC. Compruebe la configuración del firewall.
         ......................... DC2 no superó la prueba Connectivity

Realizando pruebas principales

   Probando servidor: Default-First-Site-Name\DC2
      Omitiendo todas las pruebas porque el servidor DC2 no responde a las solicitudes de servicio de directorio.


   Ejecutando pruebas de partición en: ForestDnsZones
      Iniciando prueba: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones superó la prueba CheckSDRefDom
      Iniciando prueba: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones superó la prueba CrossRefValidation

   Ejecutando pruebas de partición en: DomainDnsZones
      Iniciando prueba: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones superó la prueba CheckSDRefDom
      Iniciando prueba: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones superó la prueba CrossRefValidation

   Ejecutando pruebas de partición en: Schema
      Iniciando prueba: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema superó la prueba CheckSDRefDom
      Iniciando prueba: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema superó la prueba CrossRefValidation

   Ejecutando pruebas de partición en: Configuration
      Iniciando prueba: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration superó la prueba CheckSDRefDom
      Iniciando prueba: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration superó la prueba CrossRefValidation

   Ejecutando pruebas de partición en: MYORGANIZATION
      Iniciando prueba: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... MYORGANIZATION superó la prueba CheckSDRefDom
      Iniciando prueba: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... MYORGANIZATION superó la prueba CrossRefValidation

   Ejecutando pruebas de empresa en: MYORGANIZATION.COM
      Iniciando prueba: LocatorCheck
         ......................... MYORGANIZATION.COM superó la prueba LocatorCheck
      Iniciando prueba: Intersite
         ......................... MYORGANIZATION.COM superó la prueba Intersite

At some point I pointed DC1 to DC2 as primary DNS and DC1 as secondary DNS and vice versa in DC2 but I guess I did something wrong because after restarting DC1 it was on a boot loop without making it past "Please wait for the group policy client" or some other message.
I did not touch WINS, I did delete some DNS entries regarding LDAP pointing to DC2 to see if it would start using DC1 to authenticate users but no.
And right now I can't do anything in DC1 because I always get "Server is non operational" and similar errors.
Also, DC2 is set to read only. And DC1 if I open DNS I get access denied (I tried removing DNS role, restarting and reinstalling the role to start from scratch).
FSMO Roles:
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADForest myorganization.com | fl GlobalCatalogs
GlobalCatalogs : {DC1.MYORGANIZATION.COM, DC2.MYORGANIZATION.COM}



PS C:\Windows\system32> netdom query fsmo
Maestro de esquema          DC1.MYORGANIZATION.COM
Maestro nomencl. dominios   DC1.MYORGANIZATION.COM
PDC                         DC1.MYORGANIZATION.COM
Administrador de grupos RID DC1.MYORGANIZATION.COM
Maestro de infraestructura  DC1.MYORGANIZATION.COM
El comando se completó correctamente.



DC1 192.168.1.9 GC
PS C:\Users\daviid> repadmin /showrepl
Repadmin can't connect to a "home server", because of the following error.  Try specifying a different
home server with /homeserver:[dns name]
Error: An LDAP lookup operation failed with the following error:

    LDAP Error 81(0x51): Server Down
    Server Win32 Error 0(0x0):
    Extended Information:

DC2 192.168.1.20 GC RODC
PS C:\Windows\system32> repadmin /showrepl

Repadmin: ejecutando el comando /showrepl en el DC completo localhost
Default-First-Site-Name\DC2
Opciones de DSA: IS_GC DISABLE_OUTBOUND_REPL IS_RODC
Opciones de sitio: (none)
GUID del objeto DSA: bb2ad125-79e5-4d8a-975a-c9e62e1827a7
Id. de invocación de DSA: 9d4d6c31-64fd-45f3-8e9d-6bdb1d640082

==== VECINOS DE ENTRADA ======================================

DC=MYORGANIZATION,DC=COM
    Default-First-Site-Name\DC1 vía RPC
        GUID del objeto DSA: feb76bdd-6ac3-4219-bd64-35ff0c22debd
        El último intento, efectuado el 2024-06-03 13:58:30, se completó correctamente.

CN=Configuration,DC=MYORGANIZATION,DC=COM
    Default-First-Site-Name\DC1 vía RPC
        GUID del objeto DSA: feb76bdd-6ac3-4219-bd64-35ff0c22debd
        El último intento, efectuado el 2024-06-03 12:59:32, se completó correctamente.

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MYORGANIZATION,DC=COM
    Default-First-Site-Name\DC1 vía RPC
        GUID del objeto DSA: feb76bdd-6ac3-4219-bd64-35ff0c22debd
        El último intento, efectuado el 2024-06-03 12:59:32, se completó correctamente.

DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=MYORGANIZATION,DC=COM
    Default-First-Site-Name\DC1 vía RPC
        GUID del objeto DSA: feb76bdd-6ac3-4219-bd64-35ff0c22debd
        El último intento, efectuado el 2024-06-03 12:59:32, se completó correctamente.

DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=MYORGANIZATION,DC=COM
    Default-First-Site-Name\DC1 vía RPC
        GUID del objeto DSA: feb76bdd-6ac3-4219-bd64-35ff0c22debd
        El último intento, efectuado el 2024-06-03 12:59:32, se completó correctamente.


I'm not really sure what "isolate connections coming from the outside" is supposed to mean here. Is it meant to "protect" the main DC somehow? (If so, that really doesn't make sense – if it's a standard writable DC, then it's just as much of a 'main DC' as any other so it's equally as much of a target as the other DC that it allegedly protects...) Or do you mean that .1.9 is accessible from Internet while .1.20 is not?

As for the LDAP connection problem though, what is the connect errno that you get from adding the -d 1 option to ldapsearch?

1.9 and 1.20 are 2 different physical servers in a rack, what I've been told is, that an external company we work with will connect to 1.20 which will have the data and apps they need while 1.9 is our own server with our apps and websites. Technically none are accessible from the internet (they need to use wireguard), also, I think 1.20 shows up as read only, I'm not knowledgeable with Windows Server so I don't know how to confirm that. Added the -d 1 output of both IPs to main post

The output seems to say that the main DC accepted the connection in general (so firewall is not the problem, at least), but did not handle the request, so the next place I'd look would be LDAP service event logs.

If it's a RODC meant for an external company, then that kind of makes sense (is it some kind of forest trust?), but then there's no point for it to be used by your own work computers if a writable DC is right next to it... (And on another note – "apps and websites" really should not be hosted on a DC.) As for ismServ, from what I know, it is specifically for replication over SMTP (yes, AD over email) so it's likely not relevant in the modern era where the DCs can run continuous replication over RPC.

I enabled Field Engineering diagnostic event logging (dsdbutil.exe only shows NTDS) and tried to do an ldapsearch but I don't see any errors in  Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Directory Service, I only see Event IDs 2041 and 1644

Also added the output of connecting to both IPs with ldp.exe

When you say "there's 2 DCs, 192.168.1.9 and 192.168.1.20." these are both Windows Server 2022 DCs? Any reason you are not using LDAPS as opposed to LDAP in the communications and queries? I normally do not put websites and applications on DCs so best to avoid that. What did you change exactly? Which server has which fsmo roles assigned? What you see when you run repadmin /syncall /AdeP from a DC? How about dcdiag? Did you change any TCP/IP including DNS or WINS settings on either of the DCs? What exactly did you change? Do you not have full system AD DC backups?

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle updated question with response as it's too long

Look over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/360951/prblems-with-dc-replication?childtoview=372937&page=2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/360951/prblems-with-dc-replication?page=1#answers to help troubleshoot. I think it's going to take some digging running command, checking output, looking up errors, researching those and seeing if it gives other things to check or test to see if you can find. I think your DNS is fine, I have 4 DCs per domain so set mine up differently since I have 4 per domain. Check your SOA and other DNS records per the post guides.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I added the output of repadmin /showrepl on both DCs as for DNS records I can see the ones on DC2 but not modify them as it's RODC, DC1 I can't even open it because it says access denied.

TO fix the DNS access denied I've tried netdom resetpwd but I get The machine account password for the local machine could not be reset. The specified network resource or device is no longer available. The command failed to complete successfully.

Maybe stop the KDC service on DC1, set to manual, then try to reset, and set the KDC back to automatic: https://community.spiceworks.com/t/unable-to-reset-machine-account-password/414411/3 be sure you are using the domain admin credential. Confirm that the account used is indeed a domain admin AD group membership wise. See here too: https://www.reddit.com/r/activedirectory/comments/12s46jj/resetting_secure_channel_not_working/
